# How do we add the 'Inclusive of all taxes' label after the original price of the product on the product page in magento2?

Tags: php, html, label, magento2, magento2.2

Please help me how I can display the label 'Inclusive of all taxes' after the original product price on the product page in the magento2 platform?

And also let me know the file structure where I can easily add the HTML code to show the same.

see the screenshot for your reference: https://prnt.sc/10hqx9e

```
<div class="product-info-price"><div class="price-box price-final_price" data-role="" data-product-id="" data-price-box=""><span class="label-taxes"><label>Inclusive of all taxes</label></span></div></div>
```

The above code is just a dummy code but I have used the default div structure of magneto2 of product pages.

Please help!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can anyone help me to add the simple label on the product page?

Answer (score 2):

First If you want to display custom text only in product view page, then create catalog_product_view.xml in your custom theme on path app/design/frontend/Your-theme/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

add this Code

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.text" template="Magento_Catalog::view/customtext.phtml" after="product.info.price"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Now create customtext.phtml file on path app/design/frontend/Your-theme/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/view/customtext.phtml

Add below code

```
<div class="product-info-price">
    <div class="price-box price-final_price">
        <span class="label-taxes">
            <label><?php echo __("Inclusive of all taxes") ?></label>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to clear cache:)

Comment: It is working fine dear. See the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/15w8jmn

It is showing after border lines, so can we put it before the border lines or after the price value if possible then please suggest.